# Pause flash player (from script/media button)

Tags: firefox, flash

I would like being able to play/pause youtube videos (or other flash player instances showing videos) using the media keys on my keyboard (or from a script).

I could not find a suitable firefox plugin.

I can send a SIGSTOP signal to plugin_container, which works great to stop the flash player. Unfortunately it also freezes firefox. Sending SIGCONT unfreezes both the pluginsand firefox.

If there is a solution for chrome, I would gladly like to hear it also.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Flashblock extension is no good at all for you, keyboard controlled or not? It works from keyboard with TAB and ENTER.

Comment: can it do play/pause? The description only mentions blocking flash from loading..

Comment: Yes, but you have to use TAB key once or more than once to select the window where video is played. Key Enter activates video. YouTube videos are tricky - [sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3HlFewKByw). For this sample video you have to press TAB a few times in a row to select video window. Once selected, press Enter, and now your keyboard's play/pause buttons should work, or not. You can try them right from the start without using TAB key but I can't promise nothing. You can uncheck **Block HTML5 video as well** in flashblock extension preferences or not, your choice.

Comment: I am looking for an automated solution, this requires manual user input and visual feedback to select the correct tab.

Comment: Well, it is the player's window that has to be selected, and to do this you  press tab until that window is highlighted. Then you press Enter, and after that you can use special Pause/Play buttons from your keybord. I'm no expert, it is all I could think about. But is it too hard to just use a mouse pointer to activate your videos?